# Sending an email through c# with a custom domain from gmail

Tags: c#, email, smtp, system.net.mail

So... I have a project in Visual Studio 2015, coded in C#, that sends emails, everything works fine with commom gmails and hotmails, SSL enabled, ports, etc... They are able to send emails and to authenticate.

But now my studio has a gmail custom domain, as such info@ourDomain.com, so I used the same properties I would to send a normal gmail.

And then, I get an error 5.1.1, The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. All other gmails are working.

Do I need to change the smtp server? The port? Tried everything so far... no help.

PS: Yes I have enabled low secure apps on gmail.

Comment: What mail server are you using?  It looks like you need to set Use Network Credential to true for custom domain while using gmail set Network Credentials to false.

Comment: So... Are you referring to the UseDefaultCredentials property? Because I'm already using a NetworkCredentials, and I have set that property to true and false... Nothings changes... ;(

The thing is, the domain is a custom domain, but it is a gmail-email, and it seems the smtp is gmail too... But I can't get it to sign in...

Comment: SMTP is a protocol defined by the IEEE as part of the RFC standards.  SMTP supports secure and non-secure email and uses a different port number for secure and non-secure.   SMTP has lots of options and each e-mail server uses different options.  You should be able to send to your custom domain through your gmail account.  I don't know what options your custom domain supports so I can't  give a specific solution.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this tutorial I think it has what you need...

http://www.afterlogic.com/mailbee-net/docs/advanced_smtp_connections.html

please if I helped you and the problem solved mark my answer as the question answer...

Comment: Not quite, it's kinda cool, but I'm already using System.Net.Mail, I don't wanna change my whole system, just solve this issue... Thanks anyways